# Ubuntu server 'partially' responsive

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, elasticsearch, docker-swarm

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server that has periodically unresponsive - I can ping it, and it appears that some https services are running (albeit v. slowly), however it hangs if I try to log in (on the console and SSH). I'm prompted for the username and password and it hangs after entering the password. If intentionally enter the wrong password it returns an access denied. I can't find anything in the syslogs that correspond to the issue.

In terms of services, it's running several docker containers in a 3 node swarm and an Elasticsearch node.

I don't expect anyone to have the answer, but any thoughts on what troubleshooting I could a attempt would be appreciated, or if someone has seen something similar.

Many thanks.

Comment: why not reboot it?

Comment: I agree, time to reboot. Then install updates and reboot again.